# Resolve Logcat warning message

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, logcat, roboguice

When I run my app on **Android 2.2.3 (API 10)** device, I constantly get the following warning & error message from **logcat**

```
03-11 10:41:51.509: V/ACTIVITY onCreate()(7585): ok
03-11 10:41:51.519: W/dalvikvm(7585): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 30: Landroid/app/Activity;.getFragmentManager ()Landroid/app/FragmentManager;
03-11 10:41:51.519: E/dalvikvm(7585): Could not find class 'android.app.Fragment', referenced from method net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateManager.fragmentsSupported
03-11 10:41:51.519: W/dalvikvm(7585): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 24 (Landroid/app/Fragment;) in Lnet/hockeyapp/android/UpdateManager;
03-11 10:41:51.519: W/dalvikvm(7585): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 30: Landroid/app/Activity;.getFragmentManager ()Landroid/app/FragmentManager;
```

But, on **Android 4.1.1** device, there is no such problem.

I am wondering, what does the warning & error messages mean?

**P.S.** I have the following definition in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

My app is using the [RoboGuice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/) **fragment**, all my fragments **extends** `RoboFragment`.

And my **Activity** extends `RoboFragmentActivity`

They should be compatible with pre API 11.

And my problem only happen after I logged in,then close the app, and start the app again. The app works fine on Android 2.3.3 when just start the app to show the 1st fragment without login.

Comment: Fragments are not supported on earlier versions of Android. You can use support libraries to get past this problem. If your app makes extensive use of fragments, you might not be able to target it to earlier version eg.API10

Answer (score 3):

This message is coming from HockeySDK (I am the maintainer of this SDK). The SDK is checking if the fragment API is available (see [here](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Android/blob/master/src/main/java/net/hockeyapp/android/UpdateManager.java#L172)) and falls back to a 2.x compatible view if not. It should not affect the behavior of your app or lead to crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if you are using fragrant and don't receive this massage when running on 4.* devices then the problem is that you are not using the `FragmentActivity` and `SupportFragmentManager` from the **android-support-v4** package.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post, actually, I am using RoboGuice fragment